# fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to publish AWS VPC Flow Logs from account A to S3 bucket in another account B. I am able to do so but when i try to download the logs from account A, i am getting the error

> fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

My account A has IAM userA that i am using.

I am using the below command to download:

```
aws s3 cp s3://vpcflowlogscross/VPCLogs/{subscribe_account_id}/vpcflowlogs/{region_code}/2021/06/14/xyz.log.gz .
```

I have tried adding the region as well in the above command but no luck. Also while investigating this i came across documentation to add ListBucket permission which i already have.

My bucket policy in account B:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DownloadObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/userA"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross",
                "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross/*"
            ]
   ]
}
```

I am using the below IAM user policy in account A to download the objects that are in account B S3 bucket.

My IAM user policy in account A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IAMAllowDownload",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross",
                "arn:aws:s3:::vpcflowlogs-cross/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried changing the bucket and IAM policy but still not luck. I understand that the log objects getting published to the account B are owned by it but i am using the s3 "getobject" permission in bucket policy for the account A Principal userA shouldn't this allow me to download the objects.

Comment: This means that the principal (e.g, a user) accessing the object does not have the read permissions. Did you attach the IAM policy to your user or to some role?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did attach the policy with getobject and listbucket permissions to the iam user but that did not help me in this case. I am able to list contents of the bucket but not download them. Kindly if you can look into my Bucket and IAM policy and check what exactly do i need to change.

Comment: Looks good to me. The one thing I noticed is that you use different bucket names in the policies(with a  dash) and in the CLI command (without dash)...

Comment: Thanks yeah it was my typo I am using the command 
aws s3 cp s3://vpcflowlogs-cross/VPCLogs/{subscribe_account_id}/vpcflowlogs/{region_code}/2021/06/14/xyz.log.gz .